# How generate raw query to sequelize in node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

i want to generate SELECT * from iqrosantris GROUP BY santriId DESC to sequelize,

in this code cannot display what i want

```
try {
  const data = await Iqrosantri.findAll({
    group: ["santriId"],
    order: ["DESC"],
    include: [
      {
        all: true,
      },
    ],
  });
  res.status(200).json({ data });
```

Comment: I'm not sure `GROUP BY` with a single column would work if you want to select all columns (indicating `*`). What's the meaning of such a query?

Comment: i want to get latest record from 2 table join. but result first record no latest record

Comment: The SQL query doesn't match `get latest record from 2 table join`. Could you show more relevant SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM iqrosantris ORDER BY iqrosantris.id DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615)AS test JOIN santris ON santris.id=test.santriId GROUP BY santriId;

solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).